# Changing from degrees to meters with QChainage plugin?

Tags: qgis, qchainage

I have some difficulties changing degrees to meters,
My CRS is `WSG84, EPSG:4326`,

On googling they all change the CRS to handle it (some CRS will be meter when using QChainage), but I can only use this,

Is there any solution that can help me to change degrees to meters?

[image]

Comment: It's unlikely that you can change the plugin. You will have to project your layer to something metric instead.

Answer (score 1):

The best way will be to reproject to coordinate system in metric unit (after adding your points you can project back in the original coordinate system).

If you really dont want to reproject and accuracy is not crucial you may try to calculate an proximate conversion between degree and meter but you will need to take in account the latitude and the orientation of your line (The north-south scale factor is always 111320, but the east-west scale factor is 111320*cos(latitude*pi/180) and it still will not be accurate....